# Android Studio Setup crashing while launch

Tags: android, android-studio

I am successfully installed android studio setup.while launch android studio crashing.how to solve this.while installation setup not showing anything.

How to solve these crash

Comment: what is the error you r getting? which OS ur using?

Comment: Hi Vinay,i am using windows8.1 and 32 bit.Android studio crashing while launch

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: Would be helpful if there is any error print screen or dump file instead of saying it has crashed.

Comment: Hi Gene.I am not getting anything i am seen setup successfully installed and clicking finish.its shows android studio splash and hide no error logs.

Comment: No Vinay.How can i get logs while launch android studio.

Comment: C:\Users\<yourid>\.AndroidStudioPreview\system\log NOTE: Change your path accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are getting this problem beacause you haven't installed **jdk** on your machince . You should install **jdk** first and set **JAVA_HOME** environment variable .